# Is there no TFS Snapin for PowerShell on x64?

Tags: c#, tfs, powershell

I am trying to use the TFSSnapin in PowerShell from C# code using System.Management.Automation from the PowerShell SDK, however I would like to compile it using "AnyCPU". When I try debugging it in any CPU I get the "No Plugins Registered" error, I try debugging it in x86 mode and it works just fine. Is there anyway to get the Plugins registered on x64 PowerShell so I can use AnyCPU? Or am I just out of luck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  And it can't be changed until TFS 2010 Beta 2 at earliest.  See: [Why is the TFS Powershell snapin marked 32-bit only?](http://richardberg.net/blog/?p=51)

Answer (score 4):

This is now possible

Execute the following line in your 64-bit PowerShell command prompt

```
copy
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
 HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
-r
```

Then add the PSSnapin for `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run the 64-bit version of InstallUtil to install the snapin info to the 64-bit registry (not the Wow registry node).  If you start a 64-bit Visual Studio Command Prompt, it should have the path configured to execute the 64-bit version of installutil.exe.

Comment: I cannot use the 64 bit InstallUtil as it just says the dll is the incorrect format. It appears they only have 32 bit dll's so maybe I just cannot do it.

Comment: That's weird.  We build the PSCX snapin as AnyCPU and I'm able to register it and use it in a 64-bit Powershell prompt.

Comment: The TFS snapin in the TFS PowerTools was built for x86 only.  He's not recompiling the TFS PowerTools snapin.

Comment: Oh I misinterpreted.  I thought he had source code for the snapin and was trying to do just that - recompile it to target Any CPU. Doh!