# PowerShell (2.0, 32-bit) can't load TFS 2010 snap-in... except when it can

Tags: powershell, tfs

I have a PowerShell script which interacts with Team Foundation Server. When I run it in the PowerShell console, it works perfectly. This is nice for testing it, but I want to run it by double-clicking on it, or on a batch file or something. I'd even settle for right-clicking on it and selecting "Run with PowerShell".

But when I do that, I get an error. "Run with PowerShell" closes the window too fast to see what the error is. Somebody was really thinking when they designed that, maybe Ballmer was involved. I can also run it in cmd.exe, like so:

```
PowerShell -File dostufftocheckouts.ps1
```

When I do that, I get to see an error message, and I'm guessing it might be the same one:

```
Get-PSSnapin : No Windows PowerShell snap-ins matching the pattern 
'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' were found. Check the pattern and then 
try the command again.
```

The following code is included in the script before anything else:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin -Name  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null )
{
    Add-PsSnapin  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

When I start a new instance of the interactive PowerShell shell and run the script in that, everything works perfectly.

**UPDATE**

I get the same error with either of the following PowerShell executables (since I seem to recall the TFS snapin was 32-bit only):

```
C:\windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

In cmd.exe, the following command produces the following output:

```
c:\ powershell -Command "get-pssnapin -registered | where { $_.Name -eq 'TfsBPAPowerShellSnapIn' }"

Name        : TfsBPAPowerShellSnapIn
PSVersion   : 2.0
Description : This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes Team Foundation Server cmdlets.
```

So, I've written a very minimal script, joke.ps1:

```
Add-PsSnapin TfsBPAPowerShellSnapIn

$server = Get-TfsServer tfsserver/DefaultCollection
```

And I run it:

```
c:\ powershell -File .\joke.ps1

The term 'Get-TfsServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\jmcnamara\PowerShell\broken.ps1:3 char:24
+ $server = Get-TfsServer <<<<  gearys/DefaultCollection
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-TfsServer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Add-PsSnapin doesn't give me an error. But adding the snap-in doesn't make any of the snap-in's cmdlets visible to the rest of the script.

Allegedly, [Add-PsSnapin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849705.aspx) adds a snap-in to the current session:

> The Add-PSSnapin cmdlet adds registered Windows PowerShell snap-ins to
>   the current session. After the snap-ins are added, you can use the
>   cmdlets and providers that the snap-ins support in the current
>   session.

"You" can, eh? "You" who? Yeah, sure you can.

But how?

Comment: start powershell with the -noexit parameter and we can see the error.

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger Same error.

Comment: possible sandbox issue ??   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/470f5aa6-ca6f-4d7b-a315-75d9239897fc/powershell-script-works-from-interactive-session-but-not-from-asp-session

Comment: @Knuckle-Dragger Yeah, sounds like you're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question turns out to have been almost a duplicate of [Is there no TFS Snapin for PowerShell on x64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306858/is-there-no-tfs-snapin-for-powershell-on-x64?rq=1), [TFS Power Tools 2008 Powershell Snapin won't run in on 64-bit in Windows 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501237/tfs-power-tools-2008-powershell-snapin-wont-run-in-on-64-bit-in-windows-2008-r2?rq=1), and probably others.

I don't understand why different snap-ins were listed as "registered" the 32-bit PowerShell console vs running 32-bit powershell.exe (the WOW64 one is 32-bit) in cmd.exe, but whatever.

The answer [appears to be here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a116799a-0476-4c42-aa3e-45d8ba23739e/tfs-power-tools-2008-powershell-snapin-wont-run-in-on-64bit-in-windows-2008-r2?forum=tfspowertools): The installer doesn't properly add the TFS snap-in to the Registry. The link shows you how to set it up to be usable from 64-bit PowerShell, but it appears that you need to do the same, at a different key, to make it usable from 32-bit PowerShell outside of the PowerShell console. So you paste the following into `tfskludge.reg`, double click it, and it should make the snap-in available in both PowerShells:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell]
"PowerShellVersion"="2.0"
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Description"="This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft"
"DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"Version"="10.0.0.0"
"ApplicationBase"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools"
"AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
"ModuleName"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
"CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell]
"PowerShellVersion"="2.0"
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Description"="This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft"
"DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"Version"="10.0.0.0"
"ApplicationBase"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools"
"AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
"ModuleName"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
"CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"
```