# TFS Build: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfsbuild, build-automation, tfs-power-tools

When I'm logged in to tfs build server using local account and execute following powershell command:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
```

it loads the tfs cmdlets correctly. However, when I trigger a build on tfs server that invokes the script, it fails with message:

> 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.

The build agent runs under service account. What should I do?

**EDIT**:
I had to edit the reqistry entry from the first link in @Alexis Coles' answer to make it work with version 2015 of TFS PowerTools:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell]
"PowerShellVersion"="4.0"
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Description"="This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft"
"DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"Version"="14.0.0.0"
"ApplicationBase"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools"
"AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
"ModuleName"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
"CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell]
"PowerShellVersion"="4.0"
"Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
"Description"="This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft"
"DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
"Version"="14.0.0.0"
"ApplicationBase"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools"
"AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
"ModuleName"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools\\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
"CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"
```

Double check `AssemblyName`, `ApplicationBase`, `ModuleName` and `Version` entries. Script above works with **Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to have a quick punt here and say it is probably something to do with 32-bit vs 64-bit powershell.  If I run Add-PSSnapinicrosoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell from normal 64-bit powershell fine.  But if I run it from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe I get the above exception.  I am going to go ahead and say that the build server is a 32-bit application and there for starting a 32-bit runtime.

Not really sure what the fix is exactly but maybe the following will point you in the right direction.

[PowerShell (2.0, 32-bit) can't load TFS 2010 snap-in... except when it can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575915/powershell-2-0-32-bit-cant-load-tfs-2010-snap-in-except-when-it-can)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a116799a-0476-4c42-aa3e-45d8ba23739e/tfs-power-tools-2008-powershell-snapin-wont-run-in-on-64bit-in-windows-2008-r2?forum=tfspowertools

Comment: On my machine, clicking edit on a PS script opens the (x86) version of ISE. Selecting it from the start menu opens the 64 bit version. If you get this error, pay attention to the title bar to make sure you aren't using (x86). I had never noticed this behaviour before today.

Answer (score 9):

I had this issue and to solve I notice that by default the cmdlets are not added during the PowerTools installation. You need to run a full install to make it work.

I posted here some pictures: 
https://fabiostawinski.wordpress.com/2016/07/11/the-windows-powershell-snap-in-microsoft-teamfoundation-powershell-is-not-installed-on-this-computer/

Answer (score 3):

For me it was another issue because I was trying to use Power Tools with only Visual Studio 2017 Pro installed.

For Visual Studio 2017 they didn't released `Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2017 Power Tools`. They are saying that the previous version it should work with any higher version of Visual Studio that has TFS.

The problem is that if you have only Visual Studio 2017 installed you will not be able to install `Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools` for example, because having Visual Studio 2015 (any version) installed is a requirement for installing `Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools`.

In other words I had to install `Visual Sudio 2015` then install `Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools` and then `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell` worked.

Please refer also to this:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/103642/team-foundation-server-2015-power-tools-install-is.html

Hopefully this would help somebody.