# Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell load error

Tags: powershell

I tried to execute Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell on PowerShell and it responded with the following error:

Any idea on how to restore back the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll file?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292971/tfs-build-microsoft-teamfoundation-powershell-is-not-installed-on-this-comput

Comment: It would be helpful to add the error message as text rather than a screenshot as it makes it more googlable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to  **TFS Powertools** is **not installed fully**. By default it doesn’t install the PS cmdLets.

More details take a look at this [blog](https://fabiostawinski.wordpress.com/2016/07/11/the-windows-powershell-snap-in-microsoft-teamfoundation-powershell-is-not-installed-on-this-computer/). For VS2010, you need to use this version [Team Foundation Server Power Tools December 2011](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MartinWoodward.TeamFoundationServerPowerToolsDecember2011)