# Team foundation power tool is not getting recognize by Jenkins even it's installed to it

Tags: windows, powershell, jenkins, tfs, tfs-power-tools

I have installed Team foundation power tool to Jenkins server. I have TFS 2015 installed with Full VS 2015. I want to run powershell script which pull project from TFS. I am able to run it from Jenkins server. When i try to pass that script from Jenkins build definition using powershell plugin. I am getting errors regarding Team foundation power tool. Jenkins is complaining that team foundation power tool is not installed. I tried to uninstall and reinstall tool. My Jenkins service is running under same by using which i installed this tool.  Also, this tool is not user specific. It's installed for all users. can someone please help?

> Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
>   At C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins4325377511943060199.ps1:22 char:1
>   + Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSArgument 
>      Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
>   Get-TfsChildItem : The term 'Get-TfsChildItem' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or  operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try  again. At
>   C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins4325377511943060199.ps1:25
>   char:10
>   + $items = Get-TfsChildItem $AutoDeployDir -Recurse -Server $tfsCollection
>   +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-TfsChildItem:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

[image]
as you can see, I can run it manually inside the server.

Comment: Did it work if you manually run the powershell script on Jenkins server?

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. So, I am confused what it can be? I just updated errors in questions. It's saying in first line "Add-PSSnapin: The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's an issue with tool between x32 and x64. You will need to add registry to fix this issue. copy below content in *.reg file and double click on file to install it to registry.

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell]
>   "PowerShellVersion"="4.0" "Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
>   "Description"="This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team
>   Foundation Server cmdlets."
>   "VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft"
>   "DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This is a
>   PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
>   "Version"="14.0.0.0" "ApplicationBase"="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools"
>   "AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   "ModuleName"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation
>   Server 2015 Power
>   Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
>   "CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellSnapIns\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell]
>   "PowerShellVersion"="4.0" "Vendor"="Microsoft Corporation"
>   "Description"="This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team
>   Foundation Server cmdlets."
>   "VendorIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,Microsoft"
>   "DescriptionIndirect"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell,This is a
>   PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets."
>   "Version"="14.0.0.0" "ApplicationBase"="C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Power Tools"
>   "AssemblyName"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
>   "ModuleName"="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation
>   Server 2015 Power
>   Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll"
>   "CustomPSSnapInType"="Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.TFPSSnapIn"

Don't forget to change PowerShellVersion and TFS Version based on your setup. It won't work if there is a version mismatch. 
I found it from http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=35292971&ttl=TFS+Build%3A+%60Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell%26%2339%3B+is+not+installed+on+this+computer

Answer (score 1):

According to the error

> Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this
>   computer.

May  the TFS Powertools is not installed fully. By default it doesn’t install the **PS CmdLets**.

[image]

So, simple add that during the reinstallation and then try the build with Jenkins  again.

[image]

More ways please refer this similar question: [TFS Build: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292971/tfs-build-microsoft-teamfoundation-powershell-is-not-installed-on-this-comput)

Comment: I know this and have done this while installation. As i mentioned it's working manually in Jenkins server but not working with Jenkins build definition/powershell plugin

Comment: @Meet101 Glad to here the issue fixed. Your solution and the link is just the same as the one I provided above. Sorry for the unclear,  I have noticed this could also be an issue with 32-bit vs 64-bit powershell.  Didn't expressed clearly, just said more ways in a brief survey.