# Powershell SnapIn when running in Visual Studio publish

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, pssnapin

I'm trying to run a powershell script when doing a file system publish for my project in Visual Studio, but snap-ins don't seem to be working when actually running the publish.

If I run the powershell script manually outside of visual studio the snap-in works fine, but when its executed via the publish it doesn't work.

Here is the target in the .pubxml profile.

```
<Target Name="Test" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">
    <Message Text="********************************** Test ***********************************" Importance="high" />
    <Exec Command="powershell.exe -file &quot;$(ProjectDir)\Properties\PublishProfiles\test.ps1&quot; $(ProjectDir)"/>
</Target>
```

And here is the powershell script

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
$changeset = Get-TfsItemHistory $filePath -Recurse -StopAfter 1 | Select -ExpandProperty ChangesetId
```

Which results in

```
Add-PSSnapin : The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer.
```

Im also open to not using a snap-in if a alternative exists for the `Get-TfsItemHistory` command.

Answer (score 1):

I have no personal experience of this snap-in myself but here are some thoughts at least:

- This might be a 32bit vs 64bit compatibility issue, if it works from a separate command prompt and not from inside the publish operation. Could the reason be they are running different versions?

  - Try to start a 32bit and a 64bit PowerShell prompt and run the same `Add-PSSnapin` and see if you can reproduce the error
  - See question [TFS Build: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292971/tfs-build-microsoft-teamfoundation-powershell-is-not-installed-on-this-comput)
- Check what snap-ins are available by running `Get-PSSnapin` in the publish. Most likely it's not there but you can add it using the `installutil.exe` command.

  - See example 3 from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/add-pssnapin?view=powershell-5.1#exampleshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/add-pssnapin?view=powershell-5.1#examples) page