# Add-PSSnapin Windows 10

Tags: powershell, tfs, windows-10

I am trying to connect and get change sets from my TFS. For that I used this command:

```
powershell -Command "get-pssnapin -Registered
```

I got result like

```
Name        : Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
PSVersion   : 2.0
Description : This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the Team Foundation Server cmdlets.

Name        : WDeploySnapin3.0
PSVersion   : 2.0
Description : This is a PowerShell snap-in that contains cmdlets for managing Microsoft Web Deployment infrastructure.
```

But when I used this command:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
```

I am getting this result:

```
Add-PSSnapin : Cannot load Windows PowerShell snap-in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.
PowerShell because of the following error: Could not load file or assembly
'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerTools.PowerShell.dll' or one of its
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSnapin], PSSnapInException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

Comment: Which version of TFS and VS are you using?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools
This version is there in my system .
VS 2017

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell` snap-in is from TFS powertools. It seems you have an old version of powertools installed on your machine. I've tested with TFS 2015 powertools on my 64-bit Win10, and got a successful response.

[image]

You could check your powertools version and check case [TFS Build: `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell' is not installed on this computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292971/tfs-build-microsoft-teamfoundation-powershell-is-not-installed-on-this-comput) to see whether the solution helps you.

By the way, you could use [.NET client libraries for VSTS (and TFS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts) instead of powertools snap-in.

Comment: I have this folder in my system "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools"
I am using VS 2017

Comment: Do you have other version of powertools? You may try on another machine to see whether you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: I have 2010 , 2013 , 2015 power tools in my computer

Comment: It seems your script get the old version 2.0 instead of the 2015 version. You could try to add the 5.1 version to the session.